# postgresql empty array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
   Column    |          Type          |                         Modifiers
-------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 description | text                   | not null
 sec_r       | integer[]              |
```

My two array of integers `sec_r` have some fields that have "null" values, but I guess it isn't null?

Whenever I try to `select * from this table where sec_r = null` I get 0 rows.

```
|  description     |  sec_r  |
+------------------+---------+
| foo bar foo bar  |         |
| foo bar foo bar  | {1,2,3} |
| foo bar foo bar  |         |
| foo bar foo bar  | {9,5,1} |
(4 rows)
```

Doing select * from TheTable where 1 = ANY (sec_r) returns the correct rows however.

**How do I select the rows where the array is blank?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `IS NULL` and not `= NULL` in SQL.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE sec_r IS NULL
```

Comment: Genius. Hahaa, okay I'll accept this in the 11 minute timeout.

Comment: You can also enable transform_null_equals property, so `sec_r = null` will be treated as `sec_r IS NULL` or use `ISNULL` shorthand, but your best friend is SQL standard way `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for **IS NULL.**